# If we group by multiple columns but want distinct column values in one of the column

Tags: postgresql, unique, distinct, group

If we have a table named Employees which contains columns emp_name, dept_name, year and salary.

Following are the row headers and values:
(emp_name,    dept_name,    year,    salary)
(Nick,         sales,       2020,     20000),
(Peter,        manager,     2020,     30000),
(Nick,         sales,       2021,     22000),
(Peter,        manager,     2021,     35000),
(Sam,          sales,       2022,     25000),
(David,        manager,     2022,     40000)

Now I want to select emp_name, dept_name, year and salary, and group by dept_name, emp_name. But I want distinct emp_name with max salary.

I tried a query:

select emp_name, dept_name, salary from Employees
group by dept_name, emp_name, salary
having max(salary);

output headers and values:
(emp_name,    dept_name,    year,    salary),
(Nick,         sales,       2020,     20000),
(Nick,         sales,       2021,     22000),
(Peter,        manager,     2020,     30000),
(Peter,        manager,     2021,     35000),
(Sam,          sales,       2022,     25000),
(David,        manager,     2022,     40000)

This is not the expected output.

Expected output:
emp_name    dept_name    year    salary
Nick         sales       2021     22000
Sam          sales       2021     25000
Peter        manager     2022     35000
David        manager     2022     40000

Can someone help with the query?